# mysql> host % vs host *

Tags: mysql, mariadb

`SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` yields output like the following for us:

```
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
| user             | host                                  |
+------------------+---------------------------------------+
| %                | %                                     |
| plutot_admin     | %                                     |
| plutot_dev       | %                                     |
| plutot_intrn01   | %                                     |
| plutot_intrn02   | %                                     |
| plutot_ntrn01    | %                                     |
| plutot_ntrn02    | %                                     |
| plutot_tech      | %                                     |
| plutot_ntrn02    | *                                     |
| plutouser        | *                                     |
|   ...            |       ...                             |
```

---

`%` is wildcard host, but what is the significance of `*` in the query output?

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB (but also MySQL) isn't restrictive and doesn't check the validity of a hostname (RFC 2181) and therefore doesn't claim if a host name contains an asterisk or another invalid character.

The asterisk will not be interpreted as a wild card character, wild cards are limited to percentage (%) and underscore (_).

That means someone created the user with `CREATE USER 'plutouser'@'*'` command, likely with the assumption that the asterisk will be interpreted as a wildcard character.

Comment: This is not just **any someone**.  I am seeing that any new user that is created from **cPanel** is giving rise to the `@'*'` entry.

Comment: Perhaps it applies only to the host named `*`.  Or do you have evidence that it is treated as a wild card?